# How can I access IFrame attributes in Python3?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, iframe, jupyter-notebook

I need to call a JavaScript function on an IFrame from Jupyter Notebooks using Python. How can I do this?

Python3 has an IFrame object under IPython.display.IFrame. Unfortunately, the only [documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html?highlight=IPython.display.IFrame#IPython.display.IFrame) just says it is a "Generic class to embed an iframe in an IPython notebook", without any more information.

I've googled and looked here on SO and I can't find anything about how to get access to the elements etc. contained in the IFrame.

My code is

```
frame = IFrame('files/d3-json.html',750,490)
frame
```

Where files/d3-json.html is an html file containing fairly boring JavaScript and D3 functions.